# MonoGame - Windows Phone 8.1 - Font not rendering properly in the portrait view

Tags: fonts, windows-phone-8.1, monogame

I've recently ported my "game" from the deskop project to the Windows Phone project. I set in the Game1.cs class that the supported orientations are portrait and portrait down. My problem is that it doesn't render correctly but if I add the landscape view and rotate the emulator, it renders correctly.

I want it to render as the landscape view. Can someone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that it's not an elegant solution, but placing the following lines into my MainPage.xaml.cs helped with this issue.(Tested on the Windows Phone RT project)

```
Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayOrientations.Landscape;

Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayOrientations.Portrait;
```